# How to add table format into Excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, npoi, xssf

I am trying to add table format after writing data into sheet. I came across [this blog](http://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2014/09/Excel-Insert-Format-Table-Apache-POI-Example.html) which has POI not NPOI implementation. So I tried writing slimier in C#.

Code I tried:

```
XSSFTable my_table = ((XSSFSheet)sheet).CreateTable();
CT_Table cttable = my_table.GetCTTable();
CT_TableStyleInfo table_style = new CT_TableStyleInfo();
cttable.tableStyleInfo = table_style;
table_style.name = "TableStyleMedium9";

table_style.showColumnStripes = false;
table_style.showRowStripes = true;
AreaReference my_data_range = new AreaReference(new CellReference(5, 0), new CellReference(10, 4));
cttable.@ref = my_data_range.FormatAsString();
cttable.displayName = "MYTABLE";
cttable.name = "Test";
cttable.id = 12;
```

**Note:** 
Could not find alternate for
`CTTableStyleInfo table_style = cttable.addNewTableStyleInfo();` 
as function `addNewTableStyleInfo()` not available
so tried like

```
CT_TableStyleInfo table_style = new CT_TableStyleInfo();
cttable.tableStyleInfo = table_style;
```

While writing the stream to file:

```
(await workbook.ConfigureAwait(false)).Write(stream);
```

Getting Exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

StackTrace:

```
   at NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFTable.UpdateHeaders()
   at NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFTable.WriteTo(Stream out1)
   at NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFTable.Commit()
   at NPOI.POIXMLDocumentPart.OnSave(List`1 alreadySaved)
   at NPOI.POIXMLDocumentPart.OnSave(List`1 alreadySaved)
   at NPOI.POIXMLDocumentPart.OnSave(List`1 alreadySaved)
   at NPOI.POIXMLDocument.Write(Stream stream)
   at App..Facade.MainFacade.<BuildReportAsync>d__25.MoveNext() in C:\App..\MainFacade.cs:line 215
```

If I remove table part then working fine which means something wrong while table format. Please help.

Comment: Using NPOI version 2.3.0

Comment: Hi @uwe-keim, Thanks for the response. I have idea about NullReferenceException but in my case I am missing something which is not specified in the question reference you mentioned. Please remove the duplicate marker. Thanks again.!

Comment: The question is regarding how to add table format style in excel using NPOI not NullReferenceException.